# How to extract .tar.gz on current directory? (No subfolder)

Tags: wordpress, bash, ssh

Currently when extracting the Wordpress latest.tar.gz file from shell it extracts it inside a `/wordpress/` folder.

How would I get it so it just places the files in the actual current directory?

Making an automatic script, I was thinking of doing `mv /wordpress/* ./*`
but would that work?

Comment: Solved! - I ran mv wordpress/* ./

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a first step gunzip the file:

```
gunzip latest.tar.gz
```

The latest.tar file remains.
To extract that to working folder use

```
tar -x --xform s/wordpress// -f latest.tar
```

Answer (score 18):

Use `--strip-components=1` in your tar extract command.

Comment: This is the simplest solution to the OP question. --transform is useful for more advanced file path manipulation. +1

Comment: Note, this should not be the first parameter.

Answer (score 6):

From `man tar`:

```
--strip-components NUMBER, --strip-path NUMBER
strip NUMBER  of    leading  components  from  file  names  before
extraction

(1) tar-1.14 uses --strip-path, tar-1.14.90+ uses --strip-compo-
nents
```

So first do

```
tar --version
```

then

```
tar zxvf --strip-components 1 YOURTARFILE.tar.gz
```

for version 1.14.90+, or

```
tar zxvf --strip-path 1 YOURTARFILE.tar.gz
```

for older versions.

Alternatively, you can of course make a simple command chain:

```
tar zxvf YOURTARFILE.tar.gz && mv wordpress/* . && rmdir wordpress
```

Comment: actually, you have to do tar --strip-components=1 -zxvf file.tar.gz - if you use other parameter order, tar thinks strip-parameters is a file

Comment: You can also do `tar zxvf YOURTARFILE.tar.gz --strip-components 1`